# Why are there no commas in a javascript class declarations?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm diving into the new Javascript ES6 classes and I can't understand why these class definitions don't use commas like in object literals.

Example from MDN:

```
class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }

  get area() {
    return this.calcArea();
  }

  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}
```

It's not a real problem but I feel like I'm missing something. Thanks for any direction!

Comment: *"I can't understand why these class definitions don't use commas like in object literals."*. Because it's not an object. It's totally different concept.

Comment: Probably for the same reason you don't need a comma after a normal function declaration.

Comment: The entire spec is [on GitHub](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features/blob/master/README.md), and the entire email archives of the discussions about its formation are [also available](https://esdiscuss.org/). Please do some research before asking questions on SO.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I did do some research on this before asking - I was just thinking about it in terms of objects.

Comment: Where and why do you expect there to be commas here?